# PHPunit Bug Mock assert Binary String

Tags: php, unit-testing, serialization, mocking, phpunit

i have found weird result about phpunit Mock

I ask myself if this bug is cause by UTF8 char in `serialize()`

When serialize object with `private` or `protected` the mock return something like this

```
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:error> when invoked zero or more times
Parameter 0 for invocation Bar::error(Binary String: 0x4f3a333a22466...b4e3b7d) does not match expected value.
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'O:6:"Foo":1:{s:5:"title";N;}'
+Binary String: 0x4f3a333a22466f6f223a313a7b733a32303a22002a00666f6f50726f74656374656456616c7565223b4e3b7d
```

Code

```
class Foo
{
    public $fooPublicValue;
    protected $fooProtectedValue; //BREAK
    private $fooPrivateValue;     //BREAK
}

class Bar
{
    public function error($message)
    {
        //some process
    }
}

class Baz
{
    public function exec(Bar $bar)
    {
        $bar->error(serialize(new Foo()));
    }
}

class BazTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testExec()
    {
        $loggerMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Bar')
            ->getMock();

        $loggerMock
            ->method('error')
            ->with($this->equalTo('O:6:"Foo":1:{s:5:"title";N;}'));

        (new Baz())->exec($loggerMock);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well ... what is your question, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), private and protected members are prepended with an `*` or the class name during serialization. These prepended values will have null bytes on both sides.

### A little more detail:

This means, that while invisible to the eye, the actual byte representation of the string changes. It can be made obvious using, for example, `bin2hex`:

```
class Foo
{
    public $value;
    protected $one;
    private $two;
}

$serialized = serialize(new Foo());
$expected = 'O:3:"Foo":3:{s:5:"value";N;s:6:"*one";N;s:8:"Footwo";N;}';

echo $serialized; // O:3:"Foo":3:{s:5:"value";N;s:6:"*one";N;s:8:"Footwo";N;}
echo $expected;   // O:3:"Foo":3:{s:5:"value";N;s:6:"*one";N;s:8:"Footwo";N;}

echo bin2hex($serialized);  // 4f3a333a22466f6f223a333a7b733a353a2276616c7565223b4e3b733a363a22002a006f6e65223b4e3b733a383a2200466f6f0074776f223b4e3b7d
echo bin2hex($expected);    // 4f3a333a22466f6f223a333a7b733a353a2276616c7565223b4e3b733a363a222a6f6e65223b4e3b733a383a22466f6f74776f223b4e3b7d
```

You can clearly see that one string is longer than the other. If you take a look at the fragment describing the protected `$one` property, you can spot the null bytes:

```
s:6:"*one";N

733a363a22002a006f6e65223b4e
733a363a22  2a  6f6e65223b4e
```

Now that you know where the differences are coming from, let's get to your solution.

### The Solution

By implementing the [Serializable](http://php.net/manual/pl/class.serializable.php) interface, you can use `serialize()` and `unserialize()` to return a serialized array which represents your object. As all values of an array are public, no null bytes will be inserted in the string so you can safely compare it. Your issue is solved:

```
class Foo implements Serializable
{
    public $value;
    protected $one;
    private $two;

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize([$this->value, $this->one, $this->two]);
    }

    public function unserialize($str)
    {
        list($this->value, $this->one, $this->two) = unserialize($str);
    }
}

// true
var_dump(serialize(new Foo()) === 'C:3:"Foo":24:{a:3:{i:0;N;i:1;N;i:2;N;}}');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank for the response

in my case i just delete the NUL-Byte with

    str_replace(chr(0), '', $string);

Comment: Cool! I didn't think of that at the time of writing. It makes it quite an easy fix compared to implementing your own serialize methods. If you don't mind, I'll add that to the answer.